# What is the most reliable method to block certain attachment types using Microsoft Exchange Server 2013?

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I want to start blocking attachment types that could contain malicious content. I've come across the following PowerShell snippet online:

```
New-TransportRule -Name 'Block All .ZIP Attachments' -Priority '0' -Enabled $true -AttachmentNameMatchesPatterns ' *.zip' -DeleteMessage $true
```

Is this (`-AttachmentNameMatchesPatterns`) the best method to block ZIP attachments?

Comment: Do you have a spam filtering solution in place?

Answer (score 1):

We also started to block *.ZIP attachments with the Microsoft transport engine similar [the approach](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj674307(v=exchg.150).aspx) you are using. However we found out during an audit that some malware passed our AntiVirus environment which was send as *.rar or *.jar instead *.zip. We also found out, that some user got a *.URL as attachment, which contains a URL to malware. So you might wish to block *.rar, *.jar and *.url as well (I think *.exe, *.com, *.w16, *.pif,  ... are already blocked on your side, as that's the most malicious content on our side).

*Additional: MS Exchange 2013 has a [build in antivirus engine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150547(v=exchg.150).aspx) which isn´t that bad and which you might wish to enable if not already in place to add an additional layer.*

Comment: Does the built in malware protection not scan ZIP attachments? I have not had much success with it in testing (it didn't even block Cryptolocker which has been known for years ...).